# Storing output results in Text File in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a road traffic model, where I need to store the output results in a text file. I am generating the text file using the following code,

[image]

But when I run the model, a large of amount of data gets deleted. Please see the below image for reference,

[image]

What can I do, so that I get all the data in my output text file?

Answer (score 0):

The console output has nothing to do with what you want to write to a text file. Just write to it what you need at runtime, don't worry about the console.

Make sure to not accidentally overwrite a previous text file, though. If you use the same file name, each run will overwrite your prior results